# How to get php to utilise wscript run on windows 8.1 with WAMPServer

Tags: php, windows-8.1, wampserver, wsh

Running wampserver on windows 8.1 and unable to get any response from wscript. The page doesn't render. The exe doesn't launch. mspaint is on the system. Notepad same result. Logged in as Administrator. PHP is fine I can echo, if the required php stripped. Permissions issue? Just Jumped to windwos 8.1 from XP - so a real virgin. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello
        <?php
        // put your code here
            $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
            $oExec = $WshShell->Run("mspaint.exe", 3, true);  
        ?>
        Finished
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In fact it seems maybe none of the Program Execution Functions are working - tried: system, shell_exec, exec, as well, but none of them launch the exe. If I set the last Run parameter to false, indeed the program continues to the end but the child mspaint (or any other) doesn't execute. An apache directive that i need to set, if not Win permissions? Any thoughts guys.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?